# Manatee.Trello: Card Webhook

Tags: trello, manatee.trello

Trying to use the `Webhook` feature of Manatee Trello (**BRILLIANT library**), to get real time updates to cards that users interact with on a board.

I run this code:

```
Card card = new Search(SearchFor.TextInDescription("id: 2643"), modelTypes: SearchModelType.Cards).Cards.Single();
Webhook<Card> webhook = new Webhook<Card>(card, "http://<host>/api/webhooks/incoming/trello");
```

And get this error:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY
  X-Trello-Version: 1.598.0
  X-Trello-Environment: Production
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  Cache-Control: no-store, must-revalidate, no-cache, max-age=0
  Date: Sat, 19 Mar 2016 14:22:06 GMT
  ETag: W/"76-fa944d06"
  Content-Length: 118
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
}
```

Ideas anyone? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for using Manatee.Trello!  You do have to create a webhook.  I'll work up a sample and post it for you.  Then I'll update the docs so that it's clearer.

Comment: Please create an issue on my [BitBucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/gregsdennis/manatee.trello/issues?status=new&status=open).  I'd like to track this there.  Also, I'm going to have to pass this one to the [Trello team](https://trello.com/c/88k9xddf).  They're reporting that I'm not sending valid JSON.  I'll post back here once the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in Manatee.Trello.WebApi.  It seems that Manatee.Trello.RestSharp works without issue for this call.  I will publish a fix as soon as I find the issue.

#### UPDATE

I have updated the text encoding to UTF-8.  There was also an internal issue with logging the response JSON data that has been resolved.

Please download Manatee.Trello v1.8.3 and Manatee.Trello.WebApi v1.0.3. This issue should be resolved with those versions.

Comment: Hi. Any news on this?

Comment: Still working on it.  Having trouble finding the right encoding.